# Retrieve landscape/portrait mode with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, landscape, smartphone, portrait

Is there a way to retrieve the mode of a smartphone? If it is in landscape or portrait mode? And all that accessible within PHP?

It seems Session cannot be accessed within JS. But you can do that with Cookies. Here is a snippet (not tested)

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/; domain=.example.com";
}
function eraseCookie(name) {
createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

window.onorientationchange = function() {
  /*window.orientation returns a value that indicates whether iPhone is in portrait mode, landscape mode with the screen turned to the
left, or landscape mode with the screen turned to the right. */
var orientation = window.orientation;

switch(orientation) {

 case 0:
    // If in portrait mode
    document.getElementById("google_map").style.width="300px";
    document.getElementById("google_map").style.height="200px";
  eraseCookie("orientation"); 
   createCookie('orientation','portrait','0');
    break;  

case 90:
    // If in landscape mode with the screen turned to the left
    document.getElementById("google_map").style.width="450px";
    document.getElementById("google_map").style.height="325px";
  eraseCookie("orientation");
    createCookie('orientation','landscape','0');
    break;

case -90:  
    // If in landscape mode with the screen turned to the right
    document.getElementById("google_map").style.width="450px";
    document.getElementById("google_map").style.height="325px";
  eraseCookie("orientation");
    createCookie('orientation','landscape','0');
    break;

case 180:
    // If in portrait mode with the screen flipped
    document.getElementById("google_map").style.width="300px";
    document.getElementById("google_map").style.height="200px";
  eraseCookie("orientation");
    createCookie('orientation','portrait','0');
    break;
  }
}
```

In PHP:

```
 $orientation = $_COOKIE["orientation"];
 if($orientation=="portrait"){
     // do something
}else if($orientation=="landscape"){
    // do something different
}else{
  // fallback
 }
```

Taken from [here](http://www.php-einfach.de/tuts_php_cookies.php) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045053/set-cookie-wih-js-read-with-php-problem) and [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) and [here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/iphone-windowonorientationchange-code) and [here](http://www.engageinteractive.co.uk/blog/2008/06/19/tutorial-building-a-website-for-the-iphone/).

Comment: PHP is server side so can't see things screen orientation. You'd need to use something like Javascript to detect this, then store the information in a cookie/session, and then reload and read the cookie/session in PHP.

Comment: Indeed yes - I guess it depends on what will be done once they know what the orientation is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most you could do is detect in Javascript and then send that data back to the server. Check out `window.orientation` and the `orientationchange` event.