# set cookie value in javascript and displaying it with php

Tags: php, javascript, html

i am having an output problem and i can't seem to trace the problem, here is the code:

sample.js

```
var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
var cmonth = myDate.getMonth();
var cdate = myDate.getDate();
var temp1 = m_names[cmonth];
var tempo = escape(temp1 + " " + cdate);
document.cookie=fcookie"=" + tempo;
```

output.php

```
<?php echo implode($_COOKIE)?>
```

and it displays

713qnihjmdt7mdq8eejvlcd1q1

but i want to display the date stored in the tempo variable,

i tried dispaying the tempo variabe directly and it dispalyed the right output,

any suggestions? i think i need to add a code in the php side.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045053/set-cookie-wih-js-read-with-php-problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i just changed the following

```
document.cookie='fcookie='+tempo;
```

and

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["fcookie"])) 
echo $_COOKIE["fcookie"]; 
else 
echo "Cookie Not Set";
```

Answer (score 3):

Your script has couple of mistakes, I have modified them and added some extra codes, Hope this works for you

```
<script>
    fcookie='mycookie';
    var monthname = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
    var myDate=new Date();//--->getting today's date
    var cmonth = myDate.getMonth();
    var cdate = myDate.getDate();
    var temp1 = monthname[cmonth];
    var tempo = escape(temp1 + " " + cdate); 
    document.cookie=fcookie+"=" + tempo;//-->missing cookie name and concatenation
    </script>
    <?php
    if (isset($_COOKIE["mycookie"]))
      echo $_COOKIE["mycookie"];
    else
       echo "Cookie Not Set";
    ?>
```

More about **[Javscript cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)** and **[Php Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp)**

Comment: both of my scripts are on different files, it gives me a  Notice: Undefined index: mycookie

Comment: @PatrickNarcelles I don't think that will a issue, because if a cookie is set you can access it from different file.

Comment: @PatrickNarcelles that's because your cookie was not set, check this page http://javascript.about.com/library/blwcookie.htm , it explains creating cookie setting domain path and cookie expiry date, also i have edited my answer.

Comment: now it goes to the else part, it displays Cookie Not Set, i tried your suggestion, which is to add fcookie='mycookie';

Comment: thanks for the tips sir, i just changed the following document.cookie='fcookie='+tempo; and if (isset($_COOKIE["fcookie"]))
        echo $_COOKIE["fcookie"];
       else
         echo "Cookie Not Set";

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the $_COOKIE you are seeing is the PHPSESSID cookie... You are not viewing the JS cookies. This article has good info on the relationship between PHP and JS cookies: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html