# Cookie combination Javascript/PHP on all subdomains

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

I'm implementing a 'cookie notification bar' on my website. It's a grey transparent bar
that's fixed to the bottom of the screen with the notification of the use of cookies, a
link to a page with more info and on the far right a 'close' button. The bar hides
using a display:none with a javascript on-click event. My next problem: is it possible to set a cookie within the same function that closes the bar on-click? For it doesn't seem to be working, my code:

// Just before my body tag I have:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function closeCookieBar() {
document.getElementById('cookiepolicy').style.display = 'none';
SetCookie("cookiepolicy", 1, 8)
}

</script>
```

// At the bottom of the page I have:

```
<div id="cookiepolicy" <?php if(isset($_cookie['cookiepolicy'])){ echo "style=\"display:none\""; } ?> >
<div id="cookiepolicy-wrapper">
<div id="cookiepolicy-txt">
<span id="cookiepolicy-notice">Deze website maakt gebruik van cookies. Waarom? Klik <a href="http://....nl/cookies.php" target="_blank">hier</a> voor meer informatie.</span>
<span id="cookiepolicy-accept-cookies" onclick="closeCookieBar();">Sluit</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Next issue I am forseeing: I have about 415 subdomains I want this cookie to be saved for as well, if it set on the main domain, will it work for my subdomains?

Thanks in advance!

Sander

Answer (score 0):

I may be able to help with part of this. Since you're using PHP, this PHP script can set a cookie that is available to all subdomains and subdirectories.  If you're using a domain like xxx.co.uk you may need some adjustment around lines 30-40.

```
<?php // RAY_cookie_splash_page.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);


// SHOW A SPLASH PAGE ON FIRST ENTRY, THEN COOKIE THE BROWSER TO SKIP SPLASH PAGE
// TO SEE COOKIES IN FIREFOX, FOLLOW TOOLS => OPTIONS => PRIVACY => SHOW COOKIES
// MAN PAGE: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php



// DEFINITIONS AS NEEDED HERE
define('COOKIE_LIFE', 60*60*24); // A 24-HOUR DAY IN SECONDS ( = 86,400 )



// CONSTRUCT AND SET THE COOKIE
// USE THIS TO MAKE COOKIE EXPIRE AT END OF BROWSER LIFE
$cookie_expires = 0;

// USE THIS TO MAKE A PERSISTENT COOKIE - DEFINE COOKIE_LIFE IN SECONDS - date('Z') IS UTC OFFSET IN SECONDS
$cookie_expires = time() + date('Z') + COOKIE_LIFE;

// CHOOSE THE COOKIE NAME AND VALUE
$cookie_name  = 'Fred';
$cookie_value = 'Wilma';

// MAKE THE COOKIE AVAILABLE TO ALL DIRECTORY PATHS IN THE WWW ROOT
$cookie_path    = '/';

// MAKE THE COOKIE AVAILABLE TO ALL SUBDOMAINS - DOMAIN NAME STARTS WITH DOT AND OMITS WWW (OR OTHER SUBDOMAINS).
$x = explode('.', strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]));
$y = count($x);
if ($y == 1) // MAYBE 'localhost'?
{
   $cookie_domain = $x[0];
} else // SOMETHING LIKE 'www2.atf70.whitehouse.gov'?
{
// USE THE LAST TWO POSITIONS TO MAKE THE HOST DOMAIN
   $cookie_domain = '.' . $x[$y-2] . '.' . $x[$y-1];
}

// MAKE THE COOKIE AVAILABLE TO HTTP, NOT JUST HTTPS
$cookie_secure = FALSE;

// HIDE COOKIE FROM JAVASCRIPT TO IMPROVE SECURITY (PHP 5.2+)
$cookie_http  = TRUE;

// SET THE COOKIE (BUT DO NOT BOTHER OUTPUTTING THE DEBUGGING MESSAGES)
if (setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $cookie_expires, $cookie_path, $cookie_domain, $cookie_secure, $cookie_http))
{
// echo "<br/>SUCCESS!  THE COOKIE HAS BEEN SET AND WILL BE AVAILABLE TO THE NEXT PAGE LOAD \n";
} else {
// echo "<br/>FAILURE!  THE COOKIE WAS NOT SET AS EXPECTED \n";
}



// IF THE COOKIE IS NOT AVAILABLE IN THIS SCRIPT, SHOW THE SPLASH PAGE
if (empty($_COOKIE["Fred"]))
{
   echo "<h1>SPLASH PAGE</h1>\n";
   echo "<p><a href=\"{$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]}\">CONTINUE TO SITE</a></p>\n";
   echo date('c');
   die("\nSPLASH COMPLETE");
}

// SPLASH PAGE HAS ALREADY BEEN SHOWN
echo "<h1>REGULAR START PAGE - AFTER SPLASH HAS BEEN SHOWN</h1>\n";
echo "<p><a href=\"{$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]}\">CONTINUE TO SITE</a></p>\n";
echo date('c');
die("\nREGULAR PAGE COMPLETE");
```

Comment: Ray, thanks for your help, however, my cookie had to be set with Javascript as I need it after the on-click event and then later on checked for with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your cookie in js and use it in PHP like this

```
     function closeCookieBar() {
       document.getElementById('cookiepolicy').style.display = 'none';
          var date = new Date();
          date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
          var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
          document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/; domain=.example.com";
     }

  <div id="cookiepolicy" <?php if(isset($_cookie['cookiepolicy'])){ echo "style=\"display:none\""; } ?> >
```

In place of name put name of your cookie and in domain put your domain.
Hope it  helps...

For more u may visit [Set cookie wih JS, read with PHP problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045053/set-cookie-wih-js-read-with-php-problem?rq=1)