# how to set cookie in javascript and retrieve it in php code

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies

```
function CheckIfChecked(){
   var strChoices = "";
   var chk = document.getElementsByName("check_list[]"); 
   var chklength = chk.length;
   var e = document.getElementById("select_bulk"); 
   var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;        
   var buttn = document.getElementById("bulk");
   Cookies.set(chk, e, strUser, butttn);}
```

//  want to retrive this cookie in php code below
    if(isset($_COOKIE['buttn']))
     {       // do something
     }

Comment: what's this code , `Cookies.set(chk, e, strUser, butttn);`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393935/get-read-javascript-cookie-with-php

Comment: @Ramanlfc if the code is incorrect, explain whats the problem with the code.

Comment: i want to set cookie in javascript i tried Cookies.set(chk, e, strUser, butttn); but does not work

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
In javascript

```
var key = "aaa"
var val = "bbb"
document.cookie = key + "=" + val;
```

In php

```
print_R($_COOKIE);
```

Comment: how to get the cookie of a variable key in php in abvoe code

Comment: Use $_COOKIE['aaa'] in php for above code...