# read javascript cookie with PHP on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

I have a page, return.php.  It has a line of HTML as follows:

```
<td><a href="#" dataP="<?= $partNumber[$x] ?>" onclick="popup(this)"><?= substr($avgCost[0],0,6) ?></a></td>
```

`onclick`, this calls the following popup function:

```
function popup(windowname) {  
  document.cookie = 'popupPartNumber='+windowname.getAttribute("dataP")+'; expires=Wed, 1 Jan 2070 13:47:11 UTC; path=/'
  var x = document.cookie;
  console.log(x);    
  windowname = 'popUpDiv';
  blanket_size(windowname);
    window_pos(windowname);
    toggle('blanket');
    toggle(windowname);

}
```

on this same page, this loads:

```
<div id="blanket" style="display:none;"></div>
  <div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;"">
  <a href="#"" onclick="popup(this)"><img src="/img/close.png"></a>
<?php
  $popupPartNumber  = $_COOKIE['popupPartNumber'];
  echo "<pre>";
  echo htmlentities($_COOKIE['popupPartNumber'], 3, 'UTF-8');
  echo "</pre>";
?>

</div>
```

When I start this out and I click on the HTML link, I get a console.log output that says:

```
PHPSESSID=cvbt1gvisul27nccenaeum1hh0; popupPartNumber=123456789
```

but my php echo output says: `null`

Why is the cookie that I'm setting correctly in javascript not available to php?

## Update

I changed `return.php` to say:

```
$popupPartNumber = $_POST['popupPartNumber']; //part number line
  echo "<pre>"; 
  echo "value is: " . $popupPartNumber ;
  echo "</pre>";
```

and I changed the script to read:

```
var x = windowname.getAttribute("dataP");

  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'return.php',
      data: {popupPartNumber:x},        
        success:function(data){
          alert(data);
          }
        });

console.log(x); //outputs the correct number.
```

This isn't working though... I still get no value to the php variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set cookie wih JS, read with PHP problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045053/set-cookie-wih-js-read-with-php-problem)

Comment: Are you on the same domain?

Comment: @MatjažMav interesting, that's the exact thread I'm reading right now.  Where in this thread do you see an answer to my question?  Cause I don't.

Comment: @AlexShilman yes - all of this code is on the same page.

Comment: Looks like the JavaScript code **sets** the cookie too, which means that when the page first loads (that is, when the PHP code runs) the cookie might not be set yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your php code generates html code on the server, reads cookies, and passes html to the browser. So those cookies don't exist at that time on the server. On the browser you are setting your cookies.  So after you set those cookies on the browser do an ajax call to the server and you should be able to read those cookies on the server at that time.

Comment: Beautiful.  That's kind of what I was gathering.... let me put it into an AJAX call instead.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm having a hard time with this - can you take a look at my original question and see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: I thought you wanted to read is as a cookie: echo $_COOKIE['popupPartNumber']

Comment: yeah my bad - I was testing out a few different ways to "get" it back and none of them worked... I tried initially with `$popupPartNumber = $_COOKIE['popupPartNumber'];` but that's null too.  Is there something wrong with my AJAX code?