# Why does a jquery script not run if it's being used in a php include statement from another php page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm using javascript and php to set and get cookies across pages.  I  have a script that puts a value in a cookie variable on one page and I would like to retrieve it on another page.  Let's say that my first page is called page1.html.  In page1 I use a script to store a cookie value like this:

```
 <Script>
      $(function () {
         $("#country-selector").change(function(){
         $.cookie("Ron","Happy Birthday");
      });
    });
 </script>
```

...now let's say that I have a page called page2.php.  In page2.php I have an include statement that loads page1.html like this:

```
include('page1.html');
```

Note:  Page1.html does one thing only... it has a dropdown list of countries.  If I point my browser directly to page1.html and select a country, the cookie variable is set.  However, I if use the dropdown list via page2.php, the cookie variable is not set. I check the cookie list in my browser settings to varify.

What is preventing the script from running if it's being used in an include statement from another page?

UPDATED FOR CLARITY:

Page1.php:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <?php session_start();?>


  <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.select-to-autocomplete.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">

 </head>
 <body>

 <select class="myList" name="Country" id="country-selector"  autofocus="autofocus" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">
   <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option>
  <option value="Afghanistan" data-alternative-spellings="AF افغانستان">Afghanistan</option>

 </select>
 <Script>

 $(function () {

 $("#country-selector").change(function(){

 $.cookie("Marry","Upside Down");


 });

  });


 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Page2.php

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.select-to-autocomplete.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" </script>
 <script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>

  </head>
 <body>

 <?php include ("page1.php"); ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I would recommend posting more relevant source code, we don't have much to work with here, only assumptions. Give us something to debug and it may be possible to help but we can't help with nothing to work from.

Comment: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045053/set-cookie-wih-js-read-with-php-problem)

Comment: I updated the post for clarity...however I found my issue.  It works just fine.  I just needed to remember to load the plugin for jquery cookie after jquery-1.11.1.min.js.  Order is necessary in this case.

Comment: So, you're including a full html page, into the middle of a full html page? seems a little invalid to me. You're including the same javascript files multiple times. Also, there seems to be a typo in page2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was fine except for the order in which loaded the jquery plugin.  jquery.cookie.js should be loaded last.